# How to get fields displaying in a custom plone dexterity form?

Tags: python, forms, plone, dexterity

I'm trying to avoid writing out a few hundred fields in my custom addform for a plone dexterity object.

i've created a loop that is called from my customVisitFormTemplate.pt

```
    def otherFields2(self):
    #print "this gets called3"
    customs=""

    fields = field.Fields(ISiteVisit)

    #print dir(fields)
    for r in fields:
        #print dir(r)
        #print r.title()
        if r.startswith("current") or r.startswith("landCover") or r.startswith("surrounding"):
            pass

        else:
            print 'in others', r
            customs=customs+"""<tal:field tal:replace='structure view/widgets/%s/@@ploneform-render-widget'/>""" % (r)
    print customs
    return customs
```

in the custom template i call it with this:

```html
    <fieldset>
      <legend>General Info</legend>
      <span tal:define="otherFields view/otherFields2">
        <div tal:content="structure otherFields" />
       </span>
    </fieldset>
```

however,  on execution the tal statement does not call the widget, and it  outputs to html:

```html
<tal:field tal:replace="view/widgets/siteID/@@ploneform-render-widget" />
```

if i use the following code directly in my custom temlpate:

```html
<tal:field tal:replace="view/widgets/siteID/@@ploneform-render-widget" />
```

it outputs to html and it works:

```html
<div id="formfield-form-widgets-siteVisitNotes" class="field z3cformInlineValidation kssattr-fieldname-form.widgets.siteVisitNotes">
<label class="horizontal" for="form-widgets-siteVisitNotes"> Site Visit Notes </label>
<div class="fieldErrorBox"></div>
<textarea id="form-widgets-siteVisitNotes" class="textarea-widget text-field" name="form.widgets.siteVisitNotes"></textarea>
</div>
```

how do i get my looped code from my .py file to output the same as the "direct" code?

thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using tal:repeat in your template? That's the easy way to do this. The reason it's not working now is that TAL is not recursively rendered. You'd have to use the template engine to render it inside your script, then return what's rendered. But there's no reason to do that when it's so easy to do inside your template.

Comment: i was having errors subbing in the proper variable when using tal:repeat and the output to html was just the TAL statement not the rendered statement.

Answer (score 2):

after quite some playing around, i finally got this complexity working :).

```
      <fieldset>
            <legend>General Info</legend>
            <div>
                <metal:define define-macro="widget_rendering">    <!-- not sure if this define-macro is needed -->
                    <span tal:define="widgets view/widgets/values">
                        <tal:widgets repeat="widget python:[w for w in widgets if not w.name.startswith('form.widgets.current') and not w.name.startswith('form.widgets.surrounding') and not w.name.startswith('form.widgets.landCover')]">

                            <metal:field-slot define-slot="field">
                                <metal:field define-macro="field">
                                    <tal:widget tal:condition="python:widget.id !='form-widgets-url'"
                                        tal:replace="structure widget/@@ploneform-render-widget"/>
                                </metal:field>
                            </metal:field-slot>
                            <!--</span>-->
                        </tal:widgets>
                    </span>
                </metal:define>
                <br>    <!-- to keep label and input field together -->
            </div>
        </fieldset>
```

here are still an issue in terms of having the title and input box stay together when resizing the page, but the sorting code works.